# Detecting decimals in vim

Tags: vim

I'd like to create a shortcut to convert rem to px and px to rem for CSS file in vimrc.

```
""""for converting px to rem""""
nnoremap <Leader>rem :%s; \(\d*\)px;\= string(submatch(1) / 16.0) . "rem";
""""for converting rem to px"""
nnoremap <Leader>px :%s; \(\d*\)rem;\= string(submatch(1) * 16.0) . "px";
```

The first one works but not the second one. When rem has a decimal, it doesn't convert to px.

How can I improve this code?

=======
After the help of KoRoN the following is my final solution

```
""""for converting px to rem""""
nnoremap <Leader>rem :%s;\<\(\d*\)px;\= float2nr(submatch(1) / 16.0) . "rem";
""""for converting rem to px"""
nnoremap <Leader>px :%s;\<\(\d\+\%(\.\d\+\)\?\)rem;\= float2nr(str2float(submatch(1)) * 16.0) . "px";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `\(\d\+\%(\.\d\+\)\?\)` instead of `\(\d*\)` for decimal (float).

This pattern is not perfect, but will cover most of cases.
And you should convert string to float by using `str2float`.

As a result of these, your second map should be like this:

```
nnoremap <Leader>px :%s; \(\d\+\%(\.\d\+\)\?\)rem;\= string(str2float(submatch(1)) * 16.0) . "px";
```

Comment: It shows 1.125rem as 18.0px. Is there any way to show 18px rather than 18.0px?

Comment: You can use `ceil()` or `floor()`, like this `floor(str2float(submatch(1)) * 16.0)`

Comment: Thanks. `min-width:20rem` doesn't work. I guess because there is `:` in front of `20rem` and no space. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ah, your pattern includes a white space before numbers.  Try  this pattern `%s;\<\(\d\+\%(\.\d\+\)\?\)rem;` instead. `\<` means beginning of a word.

Comment: No I meant if there is no space then it doesn't work. If there is a space it works. So I want to make it work even there is no space in front.

Comment: Did you try my last patter? Please try it.

Comment: Thanks it works. floor(str2float...) gives an error, so I use float2nr.